# Auto Inserting data into table row behind subform?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I've got a form that's got a subform and THAT subform/child has a subform/grandchild.

When I add a new client to the main form, the subform/child contains data like shipping address, etc etc.  The subform/grandchild that one contains data like what we're shipping them.

When I make my initial new entry in the top form, there's data that seems to auto populate into the subform/child (and subsequently the table), however there are things that are always "default" items to ship (third subform/grandchild) that do not do that.

I've got some table constraints for the grandchild table like (ShipPackingSlip type bit) is set to 1, so that the checkbox should always be true.  However, this does not occur on the 3rd layer of the form.   Even setting the default option value to -1 will "autocheck" the box, but the data behind the forum does not reflect that.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Does that even make sense?

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. Default data is not written to the table until it is, as it were, made real by the addition of some real data or by code.

Comment: Well, even if I have something in the child form such as: Me.ChildName.Form.CheckBox = true (this reference being to the grandchild form) and that does indeed work for that checkbox, but the "default" column values out of SQL are not. That should be enough to insert the row to get the 'default' values to apply.

Comment: It's not clear to me from your explanation, but have you set the default values in the definition of the fields in the underlying tables? Or does the default value differ for different parent records?

Comment: The underlying tables have a couple of default values set. When I insert data into the table from the access side, the default values on the SQL side are not being "added".

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it (and I could be wrong), you can't use a subform in a subform on a main form without problems.  It's better to organize your data and forms so that if you need to view more detailed information on data presented in a subform - it's better to call a new form from a button on the subform, passing a value to it so it pulls the correct record to view.

This would, of course, require you to store this subform of the subform data in a related table - then just relate it back to the main database with a unique identifier.  This allows you a bit better means to organize your data, indexing isn't a pain, and you don't repeat information entry as much.

Comment: The child and grandchild subforms are completely different tables with linkchildfield that is unique to the child and the grandchild forms.  I think what I'm doing is OK, I do it in other places, but the grandchild on the other forms is in dataset view expecting new data to be inserted by the user, none of it is 'autopopulated' as I want with this form.

Comment: Child and grandchild is by no means impossible, or even particularly difficult. I have used them often enough.

Comment: See, I wasn't sure about it (hence the 'as I undestand' part of it :) ).  I'll have to keep an eye on this question, as I am curious about grandchild forms.